# How to make links of map annotation to ui collection cell when scrolling the cell highlight the annotation

Tags: swift, scroll, uicollectionview, annotations

As the title describe the question, I have no idea which function or method to trigger the links.

I have already added all the annotations into the map.

Hope someone could give specific example code, thanks.

Comment: Hey, Welcome to Stack. It would be great to see what you've tried and any errors that you're experiencing? Post some code and someone may be able to help you make it work.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You have code that says:

   ```
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       if scrollView is UICollectionView {
           let collectionViewCenter = CGPoint(x: myMap.bounds.size.width / 2 + myMap.frame.minX, y: myMap.bounds.size.height / 2 + myMap.frame.minY)
           let centredCellIndexPath = cafeCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: collectionViewCenter)

           guard let path = centredCellIndexPath else {
               // There is no cell in the center of collection view (you might want to think what you want to do in this case)
               return
           }

           // select annotation here, if needed
       }
   }
   ```

   You’re setting the `collectionViewCenter` to the center of the *map,* but then using that as a parameter to [`indexPathForItem(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618030-indexpathforitem) If you’re trying to find `centeredCellIndexPath`, you should use the center of the collection view’s `bounds`, not the map’s.

   If your map is, like the AirBnb app, a different size than the collection view, you’re probably trying to call `indexPathForItem(at:)` for a `CGPoint` that is outside the collection view’s `bounds`, and would not get any hits in that scenario.

   So, if you wanted, for example, the center of the collection view, you’d replace `collectionViewCenter` assignment with something like:

   ```
   let collectionViewCenter = CGPoint(x: cafeCollectionView.bounds.midX,
                                      y: cafeCollectionView.bounds.midY)
   ```

   Or if you wanted to get that cell in the left edge, then use some fixed `x` value instead of `midX`.
2. Your code to select an annotation doesn’t seem to be right, either. You are doing:

   ```
   if let selectedAnnotation = myMap.selectedAnnotations.first {
       // Ignore if correspondent annotation is already selected
       if selectedAnnotation.isEqual(self.myMap.annotations[path.row]) {
           self.myMap.selectAnnotation(self.myMap.annotations[path.row], animated: true)
       }
   }
   ```

   That effectively says “if the selected annotation is the one we want, then select it.” I think you want the opposite, namely:

   - Find the annotation that should be selected;
   - If it’s not selected, then do so.